# Relocate the Categories Above the Navigation Bar

Tags: css, navigation, blogger

I want to relocate the navigation bar's categories, which are supposed to be on the background image.

How can I relocate the these categories? I couldn't find the CSS code for this.

My HTML:

```
<body>
<div id='nav'>

    <ul class='navigation'>
        <li class='navigation-Ana Sayfa'><a href='tarifi-yemek.blogspot.com.tr/aa'>Ana Sayfa</a></li>
        <li class='navigation-Tarifler'><a href='#'>Tarifler</a></li>
        <li class='navigation-Videolar'><a href='#'>Videolar</a></li>
        <li class='navigation-Tricks'><a href='#'>Tricks</a></li>
        <li class='navigation-Parties'><a href='#'>Parties</a></li>
    </ul>

    <img id='logo' src='http://i.hizliresim.com/4lQ9A7.png'/>

    <ul class='navigation'>
        <li class='navigation-P.J.Squad'><a href='#'>P.J. Squad</a></li>
        <li class='navigation-Chat'><a href='#'>Chat</a></li>
        <li class='navigation-Fanart'><a href='#'>Fanart</a></li>
        <li class='navigation-Graphics'><a href='#'>Graphics</a></li>
        <li class='navigation-Beta'><a href='#'>Beta</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class='clr'/>

<div class='container'>
    <div id='main'>

        <div class='wrapper clearfix'>
            <b:if cond='data:blog.pageType != &quot;static_page&quot;'>
            <div class='recent-posts'>
            <script>
                document.write(&quot;&lt;script src=\&quot;/feeds/posts/default/-/&quot;+cat1+&quot;?max-results=&quot;+numposts1+&quot;&amp;orderby=published&amp;alt=json-in-script&amp;callback=showrecentposts1\&quot;&gt;&lt;\/script&gt;&quot;);
            </script>
        </div>
```

My CSS:

```
#logo { float: left; }

#nav {
    background: url(http://i.hizliresim.com/gopb50.png) no-repeat scroll top left;
    background-color: none;
    width: 1300px;
    height:130px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 00px #5E5E5E;
    position:static;
    top:90px;
}

.title {
    display:none;
    color:#EDEDED;
    font-family:verdana;
    font-size:25px;
    width:350px;
    margin-top:6px;
    margin-left:150px;
    font-weight:bold;
    float:left;
}

.navigation {
    list-style-type:none; 
    float: left;
}

li { 
    display:inline;
    padding:0px;
}

#nav a {
    font-size: 1.6em;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    text-shadow: 0 0 0.3em #ffffff;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family:arial;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#e7435a;
    opacity:0.99;
}

#nav a:hover {
    opacity:0.36;
}
```